# Why do multiples of 4 mess up table.insert()?

Tags: lua, lua-table

so I was trying to test how table.insert functions when there is already an entry, and I found the behaviour that if there is an entry on a multiple of 4 prior to inserting anything into the table that is before that entry, it messes up

```
t = {}
t[4] = "this works"
for i = 1,9 do
table.insert(t,i)
end
for i = 1,#t do
print(t[i])
end
print("total: "..#t)
```

output:

```
1
2
nil
this works
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
total: 11
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An Interesting phenomenon of Lua's table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076364/an-interesting-phenomenon-of-luas-table)

Answer (score 4):

It happens because `table.insert` by default inserts elements at the position `#list+1`, but the [length operator](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7) is only defined for *sequences* and the table with gaps (as in your case `nil, nil, nil, "this works"` or `1, nil, nil, "this works"` or `1, 2, nil, "this works"`) is not a *sequence*.

You can get a bit more expected result if you use `table.insert(t, i, i)`, as this will explicitly specify where the elements need to be inserted (instead of relying on the length operator), but the insertion will still be affected by `nil` elements in the table. If you do this, after 4 insertions you may get `{1, 2, 3, 4, "this works"}` and after 5 insertions you may get `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "this works"}`, which may or may not be what you need.

(To specifically answer your question about multiples of 4: the length operator is using binary search, which also depends on the number of elements already stored in the array part of the table. When you have `1, 2, nil, 4`, the algorithms finds 2 and then finds 4, which satisfies the criterion for the length value for sequences (`n` value is not `nil`, but `n+1` value is), so it returns 4 and the next element is inserted at the position 5 and not 3 as you'd probably expect.)

Comment: for t[3] and t[5] = "this works" I have no nil entries with the example I provided

Comment: @user5888870, I updated the answer with details on multiples of 4. t[3] and t[5] work because in the first case after two insertions, #t == 3 and in the second case #t = 5 after four insertions (so the table content becomes a proper sequence in both cases).